# I used for loop in onclick event but doesnt triggered the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, fetch-api

I used for loop function to click all elements like

`for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)`

then I used
`elements[i].onclick () =>{...Code .. }`

Then it perfectly works but if you click the last part of element, it doesn't triggered.
I want to make the code that if the user click the thumbnail or title, the link or videoID will put on the iFrame. But I will not include the iFrame here, instead I using `alert()` function

Here's my code.

```js
fetch('https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=UUiNxeE13Z4zTZYG_0r3RStw&key=AIzaSyDL4P5BqSx4p-juYifPzaoNJ_8WAZSprc4')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    JSON.stringify(data.items.forEach((el) => {
      var ChannelID = [el.snippet.resourceId.videoId];
      var Thumbnails = [el.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url];
      var Titles = [el.snippet.title];

      function createTags() {
        const Blogs = $('#Main');
        for (let i = 0; i < ChannelID.length; i++) {
          const Tags = `
                      <div class="Content">
                      <input value="">
                          <div class="Thumbnails">
                      <img src=""/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Titles">
                      <p></p>
                          </div>      
                      </div>
                    `
          var VideoData = $(Tags);
          VideoData.find('input').attr("value", ChannelID[i]);
          VideoData.find('img').attr("src", Thumbnails[i]);
          VideoData.find('p').text(Titles[i]);
          Blogs.append(VideoData);
        }
      }
      var Cont = document.getElementsByClassName("Content")
      for (let i = 0; i < Cont.length; i++) {
        Cont[i].onclick = () => {
          let imageURL = Cont[i].querySelector("input").value;
          alert("You clicked this video that has a channel ID of:" + imageURL);
        }
      }
      createTags();
    }));
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

#Main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.Content {
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.Thumbnails {
  width: 100%;
  height: 161px;
  background: blue;
}

.Titles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

p {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script defer src="./app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Main">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyway, I coding this in my mobile device so I suggest you to minimize your screen of your laptop/desktop until 500px.

Comment: Anyway, the only problem on this is the last part of the element doesn't triggered. I expected that there's alert pop-up but it doesn't happen

Comment: What's the reason for `JSON.stringify()`? You don't assign the result anywhere. And `forEach()` doesn't return anything to stringify.

Comment: Is that your real API key? You should redact it here, and change it on youtube.

Comment: I get the alerts no matter where I click.

Comment: I don't understand how this is working at all. The `for` loop is before you call `createTags()`, so there shouldn't be anything to loop over at that time.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you use its simple event delegation syntax? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar Right, but it's called again and again for each item, which explains that there's no click handler for the very last one (because this one isn't there yet).

Comment: @Barmar the JSON.stringify is used to avoid some bugs like the console log said ```object Object```

Comment: But you never actually call `console.log()`, so there's nothing to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the loop to assign the click handler outside of the `data.items.forEach`:

```
fetch('https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=UUiNxeE13Z4zTZYG_0r3RStw&key=<secret>')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    JSON.stringify(data.items.forEach((el) => {
    var ChannelID = [el.snippet.resourceId.videoId];
    var Thumbnails = [el.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url];
    var Titles = [el.snippet.title];

    function createTags() {
        const Blogs = $('#Main');
        for (let i = 0; i < ChannelID.length; i++) {
        const Tags = `
                    <div class="Content">
                    <input value="">
                        <div class="Thumbnails">
                    <img src=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Titles">
                    <p></p>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                    `
        var VideoData = $(Tags);
        VideoData.find('input').attr("value", ChannelID[i]);
        VideoData.find('img').attr("src", Thumbnails[i]);
        VideoData.find('p').text(Titles[i]);
        Blogs.append(VideoData);
        }
    }

    createTags();
    }));
    var Cont = document.getElementsByClassName("Content")
    for (let i = 0; i < Cont.length; i++) {
    Cont[i].onclick = () => {
        let imageURL = Cont[i].querySelector("input").value;
        alert("You clicked this video that has a channel ID of:" + imageURL);
    }
    }
});
```

Note: I replaced your key by `<secret>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues in your code, one of them is recreating the template every time inside the `forEach` function. Also there is no need of `createTags` function. And since you are using jquery you can simple use `$('Content').click` to add the event listener to it

```js
const Blogs = $('#Main');
const Tags = `
                      <div class="Content">
                      <input value="">
                          <div class="Thumbnails">
                      <img src=""/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Titles">
                      <p></p>
                          </div>      
                      </div>
                    `
fetch('https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=UUiNxeE13Z4zTZYG_0r3RStw&key=AIzaSyDL4P5BqSx4p-juYifPzaoNJ_8WAZSprc4')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.items.forEach((el) => {
      let ChannelID = [el.snippet.resourceId.videoId];
      let Thumbnails = [el.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url];
      let Titles = [el.snippet.title];
      let VideoData = $(Tags);
      VideoData.find('input').attr("value", ChannelID);
      VideoData.find('img').attr("src", Thumbnails);
      VideoData.find('p').text(Titles);
      Blogs.append(VideoData);
    });
    $('.Content').click(function(e) {
      let imageURL = e.target.value;
      alert("You clicked this video that has a channel ID of:" + imageURL);
    })
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

#Main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.Content {
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.Thumbnails {
  width: 100%;
  height: 161px;
  background: blue;
}

.Titles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

p {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Main">

</div>
```

Comment: A semicolon is missing after your definition of `Tags`. And `e.target.value` returns `undefined`, should be something like `$(this).find('input').attr("value");` in my opinion.

Comment: @brk if you click the thumbnail and title it's return ```undefined``` but if you click the ```input tag``` it works. I want to trigger when you click the Thumbnail and Title, not only the ```input tag```

Comment: @volkerschulz "*A semicolon is missing after your definition of Tags*" - yet you'll see the  snippet still works.  In javascript, missing semi-colons are **inferred** by the javascript engine.  How it does it can lead to confusion if the coder isn't aware.  But, generally, with one-line-per-statement, semi-colons are entirely optional.

Comment: @brk True. I should have said **I'm** missing it. ;) Still `e.target` seems to be the element clicked, not the element in inherited the listener from.